# How to add a string to array in a simple way - C++

Tags: c++, arrays

So I have this problem my teacher gave me which is: Enter the names and salaries of 5 employees into two arrays and print the name of the employee who has the highest salary.

Im not sure how to input a string to an array and link it to the other array, this is what I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
int salary, x, y;
string name;
int Arr1[5];
int Arr2[5];
x = 0;
y = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    cin >> Arr1[name];
    cin >> Arr2[x];
    if (x > y) {
        x = y;
    }
}
cout << "Employee" << Arr1[name]<< "has the biggest salary of:" << y << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `int Arr1[5];` should be `string Arr1[5];`

Comment: You can't index an array with a `std::string`. What you actually need for this is a `std::map<std::string,int>`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - two arrays works just fine. Especially since that's what the assignment requires.

Comment: @PeteBecker I know well, I've been referring to the indexing style.

Answer (score 3):

I am not going to do your assignment for your. But I will fix your errors and help you approach your solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::string Names[5]; // don't use "namespace std", use std:: instead
   int Salaries[5]; // use proper variable names

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
   {
       std::cin >> Names[i] >> Salaries[i];
   }

   /* 
   Breaking down the steps:
   1 - now you have the data, structured and ready
       Names and Salaries // Done
   2 - start from here // Next do this
       find max salary // Search on how to find the max value in an array and save its index
       ....
   3 - find the employee // later
       // use the saved index and get the value from this array
       ....
   4 - display or save or what is required // later, std::cout
   */

   return 0;
}
```

What you need to think of:

Find maximum in `Salaries[]` and save the *`INDEX`* of what you find, then go to `Names[]` and get whatever `Names[]` has a value in that *`INDEX`*.

Comment: I fixed it without using the std, apparently you CAN add strings to arrays. Apparently nobody gave me the simple version of it so thanks for the effort tho.

Comment: @mar it is easy. We broke it up for you. For each step, look up on the internet and StackOverflow on how to do it. You will finish it yourself in less than an hour. You should not expect someone to give you the whole thing at once.

Comment: I have been searching but some were too advanced and notice that this is my first time programming, so I dont intend to use very advanced code in the upcoming finals (still in highschool). Although thanks for breaking it down and making it clear!

Comment: @mar I added more details. Good luck